# Read a line of unknown format in C

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

I need to write a program in C that read a text, and replaces a letter with another one. I'm a newbie in programming and up to now i always used the `fscanf` function.
How can i read a line of text without knowing the format?

I don't even know the lenght of the file...

There is my "file.txt":

```
Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,
ché la diritta via era smarrita.
Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte
che nel pensier rinova la paura!
Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;
ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,
dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.
Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,
tant' era pien di sonno a quel punto
che la verace via abbandonai.
```

i need to change every "m" with a "n" and than print out the result. Thank You for the help

Comment: You should provide some example input and output for your problem, it's not very clear what you want to do. If I understand correctly, you could just read the text, find the occurrence of the character you're looking for, and replace it with another.

Comment: if you really want to replace single letters, then you can simply use `fgetc` and `fputc`.

Comment: The "f" in "fgetc" and "fputc" means "function" ... as opposed to the macros getc and putc. fgetc and fputc should only be used when you need a function pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Just decide a maximum buffer length and read it with [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/):

```
FILE *file = fopen(...);
char buffer[256];

fgets(line,256,file);
```

Comment: if i don't know the lenght of the file?

Comment: Please read the documentation of `fgets` that is linked in my answer at least: _Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the End-of-File is reached, whichever comes first._

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { OLDCH = 'm', NEWCH = 'n' };

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        if( c == OLDCH )
            c = NEWCH;
        putchar(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have the text on a file... i can't use getchar :/

Comment: Of course you can: myfilterpgm < file.txt ... But if you must open the file in your program, then use getc and putc instead of getchar and putchar ...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* repchar(char *str, char from, char to){
    if(str != NULL){
        char *p;
        for(p=str;*p;++p){
            if(*p == from)
                *p = to;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(){
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
    //input of one line to char[] by scanf
    //%[^\n] order takes as input a non '\n'
    //%*[\n] ignore input '\n'
    while(fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*[\n]", line)==1){
        printf("%s\n", repchar(line, 'm', 'n'));
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```